# What do "]0;" and other codes mean in Linux Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, ansi-escape

I'm making a Golang program that runs a bash shell using the command `bash -i` which transfers the output through a socket and receives input through that same socket. The other side of the socket is connected to an application that gets the output and puts it into an integrated terminal in the application. Only, when running `bash -i` the first output is `]0;root@main` while I would only expect `root@main` as it's shown in the Linux terminal application. It's not the only place where I get this kind of code though, if I run `htop` I get a lot of them. Is there any website that tells me what does each of these mean?

Comment: Neither Go nor Linux are relevant here, but terminal control codes are. I updated your tags. (bash is at least marginally relevant, since it's the bash prompt settings that *use* these codes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see are [ANSI Escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Specifically `]0;root@main` is an [Operating System Command sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences) used to set the window title in Xterm.